# Why is my crontab not running

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, cron, ubuntu-12.04

I have this cron

```
38 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/rails/site/releases/20120705144335 && script/rails runner -e qa '\''Play.load_lists'\'''
```

I have this cron under the a different user so I switch users to deploy

```
sudo su deploy
crontab -e
```

and i see my cron then i tail the log under the root user

```
tail -n300 -f /var/log/syslog
```

and I see my cron

```
Jul  5 11:38:01 ip-10-70-75-234 CRON[4971]: (deploy) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/rails/site/releases/20120705144335 && script/rails runner -e qa '\''Play.load_lists'\''')
Jul  5 11:38:01 ip-10-70-75-234 CRON[4970]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

But the cron is either not running or there is a permission issue...When i run the task in the console it works great but not in the cron...any idea what i am missing

this is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Maybe i can log a more detailed list to somewhere to see the errors

Comment: According to your log, the job was run. To check it out you could have it log something, e.g. add a `&& echo "I did it">>/tmp/test.log`. Then, after it was run (according to your syslog), check your `/tmp/test.log` if it was a) created and b) has the words in.

Comment: where do i add the && echo "I did it">>/tmp/test.log should it look like this    38 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/rails/site/releases/20120705144335 && script/rails runner -e qa '\''Play.load_lists'\''' && echo "I did it">>/tmp/test.log

Comment: I noticed the 'no MTA installed', meaning you have mail output, but no way of sending it. You maybe can install one, and you'd get your info mail.

Comment: I solved the issue...i piped the error to a log file and realized I got an error looking for ruby

Comment: @Tamer: how did you pipe the error to a log file?

Answer (score 22):

CRON delivers the applications' output (stdout, stderr) via local mail.
Ubuntu apparantly does not have an MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) installed by default these days. 
CRON prints a notification into the systems logfile whenever a delivery failed:

```
Jul  5 11:38:01 ip-10-70-75-234 CRON[4970]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

You can install an MTA, e.g. postfix, for internal (local) use only, e.g.

```
aptitude install postfix
```

During the installation you will be asked what default configuration to use. You should select the `Local only` configuration.

Thereafter you can find the output of the applications ran by CRON using

```
tail -f /var/mail/<your_username>
```

---

Of course you can also write the logging output to a dedicated log file or pipe/redirect the output to a file by using built-in shell functionality...

Comment: Very useful in helping to make progress here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585424/sftp-with-redirection-and-here-doc-has-issues-under-cron. 

It astounds me that an OS wouldn't log the actual error in the log, rather than putting in an email.