# Cron job log reads 'No MTA installed', does that prevent the CRON job from finishing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, rsync, cron

I have a cron job that is just running rsync on a particular directory.

When I run the rsync command itself `sudo rsync -av --delete /directory1 /directory2`, it runs without issue and does exactly as intended.

When the Cron job runs - I see it in /var/log/syslog.1 and it says this (summarized):

```
Mar  12 11:38:01 ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx CRON[4970]: (root) CMD (rsync --delete /my/directory /backup/directory)
Mar  12 11:38:01 ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx CRON[4970]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

But the files are not in the backup directory (so it's not completing).

Does that second statement about '`No MTA installed`' prevent the completion of the cron job? What is the best way to get that cron job to complete and get rid of the MTA error?

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/445347/why-is-my-crontab-not-running) but it doesn't say if that prevents the job from finishing.

Comment: Presumably `cron` is configured to send an email and can't?

Comment: By default it is set to send an email - I have not set up an MTP - I'm aware of that. I was just wondering if that error meant the job would fail.

Answer (score 0):

The cron should run even if its showing this warning. You can test this by placing a test file and see if its being copied to destination when cron is executed.

May I know if the cron is set using "*`crontab -e`*"? Try to add the cronjob not to crontab -e but to /etc/crontab. This should fix the statement about 'No MTA installed'.

Have you written the script to send email alerts? The warning, "(No MTA installed, discarding output)", happens when a mail service is not installed.

Most Linux distributions have a mail service (including an MTA) installed. Ubuntu doesn't though.

You can install a mail service, postfix for example, to solve this problem.

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```